# can I configure FBA for two webapplication in same sharepoint farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, administration, forms-authentication

I'm new to SharePoint2013 Administration. I have SharePoint 2013 farm with 4 Web applications; one Web application is configured for FBA authentication. My question is: how can I configure FBA for another Web application in the same farm?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy for the 2nd web application.You already configure the FBA for farm as 1st web application is working fine (I am guessing).Now

- You have to make changes in the Web.config of 2nd web application.(as you did for 1st web application.)
- Update the Web application authentication from windows to FBA from central admin.
- No need to update the Sts & central admin web.config as it is one time thing.
- No need to configure the whole FBA pack as it is one time thing

Comment: Hi Waqas Sarwar, thanks for your answer, shall I use another Membership Provider and Role manager to the newly configured WebApplication?